# What if traversal order of two of pre-order, in-order and post-order is same?

Tags: binary-trees

Supposing a tree T has the identical:

1. Pre-order traversal and in-order traversal
2. Pre-order traversal and post-order traversal
3. In-order traversal and post-order traversal

How does T look like?

From the previous discussion in SO, I learned that pre- and post-order are same iff. only one node is in the T.

How about the left two conditions?

I suppose that only purely left-skewed tree can make post- and in-order the same, and only right-skewed tree can make pre- and in-order the same.

Am I on the right way?

---

Edit: To avoid being solely a 'yes' or 'no' problem, the actual doubt is that **how to prove this statement**, but I have a idea about the proofs using contradiction. So maybe this problem is a little redundant.

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper proof uses the recursive definitions of the tree-orders. Here is a sketch.

For inorder the recursive definition is: *in(left) - root - in(right)*.
For postorder we similarly have: *post(left) - post(right) - root*.

Look at the position of *root* in both orders. If we want this to be the same we need to have there are no nodes in *in(right)* which means the right subtree (at the root) is empty. Same for the root at other levels.

Answer (score 3):

Hendrik is almost right but did not conclude well. Therefore, I am giving a more comprehensive answer.

In the followings, `r` denotes root, `l` denotes left sub-tree, and `r` denotes right sub-tree. Now, let's consider each case separately, starting from the second one.

- **Pre-order is the same as post-order**: In this case `r-pre(l)-pre(r)` should be the same as `post(l)-post(r)-r`. For them to be equal both `r` and `l` should be empty trees (`null`). So the tree should only have one node as follows:

  ```
                           a
                          / \
                       null null
  ```
- **Pre-order is the same as In-order**: In this case `r-pre(l)-pre(r)` should be the same as `in(l)-r-in(r)`. For them to be equal we need to get rid of `in(l)` enforcing the left sub-tree to be empty (`null`). However, `in(r)` should be the same as `pre(r)`. Now again we need in-order traversal to be the same as pre-order traversal. ***Although formally an induction proof is required for this case***, intuitively one can observe that the tree should only have right child at every node (not necessarily a one node tree). Here is an example:

  ```
                           a
                          / \
                       null  b
                            / \
                         null  c
                              / \
                               ...
  ```
- **In-order is the same as post-order**: This is the same as the previous case but the tree should only have left child at every node.

  ```
                           a
                          / \
                         b  null
                        / \
                       c  null
                      / \
                     ...
  ```